# Zeppelin: How to use groups in active direactory (AD) to manage notebook permissions?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apache-zeppelin, shiro

Hi I am trying to use active directory (AD) groups to manage notebook permissions. But I found that I can only grant notebook permission to individual users, and not be able to give permissions to a group of users with AD groups.

For example, there are users A, B and C, and AD group named "Team" which contains them. when I grant write permissions to A, B or C separately, everything works as expected. But when the group "Team" is used, none of the permission setting works.

So I am just wondering if I could use AD original groups to manage the notebook permissions?

Here is my shiro.ini file content:

```ini
[users]

# Sample LDAP configuration, for user Authentication, currently tested for single Realm
[main]
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
iniRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

### A sample for configuring LDAP Directory Realm
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap.company.com
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = {0}@company.com
ldapRealm.searchBase= DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com
ldapRealm.userSearchBase = DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com
ldapRealm.groupSearchBase = OU=Groups,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com
ldapRealm.groupObjectClass=group
ldapRealm.userSearchAttributeName = userPrincipalName
ldapRealm.memberAttribute=member
ldapRealm.groupIdAttribute=cn
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername = CN=ADAccess,OU=UserBase,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemPassword = pssswordAD
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
ldapRealm.authorizationEnabled=true

securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager

### Enables 'HttpOnly' flag in Zeppelin cookies
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = JSESSIONID
cookie.httpOnly = true
### Uncomment the below line only when Zeppelin is running over HTTPS
#cookie.secure = true
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie

securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
# 86,400,000 milliseconds = 24 hour
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login

[roles]
admin = *

[urls]
/api/version = anon
/api/cluster/address = anon
# Allow all authenticated users to restart interpreters on a notebook page.
# Comment out the following line if you would like to authorize only admin users to restart interpreters.
/api/interpreter/setting/restart/** = authc
/api/interpreter/** = authc, roles[admin]
/api/notebook-repositories/** = authc, roles[admin]
/api/configurations/** = authc, roles[admin]
/api/credential/** = authc, roles[admin]
/api/admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
#/** = anon
/** = authc
```

Comment: what do you mean by "notbook permission" ? files/folders write permission ?

Comment: maybe specific shiro permission ? (I don't know that api)